# How to filter a list of booleans and return the index for qualified items in Dart?

Tags: dart

I am using Seive method to calculate prime numbers up to a limit (say 100).

I constructed a `List<bool>` to hold if an index (which will eventually be the number) is prime or not. This part is fine.

Finally, I need return the numbers (index). Now I am using:

```
for(var i=2;i<=max;i++) {
    if(!is_composite[i]){
      primes.add(i);
    }
}
return primes;
```

This will give the correct list containing only the prime numbers.

I am wondering if I can do a filter on `is_composite` and returns the "index" associated?

As requested, the complete code:

```
List<int> findPrimes(int max) {
  var is_composite=List<bool>(max+1);
  var primes=List<int>();

  is_composite.fillRange(0, max, false);
  for(var i=4;i<=max;i+=2) {
    is_composite[i]=true;
  }

  var next_prime=3;
  var stop=sqrt(max);

  while(next_prime<=stop) {
    for(var i=next_prime*2;i<=max;i+=next_prime) {
      is_composite[i]=true;
    }
    next_prime+=2;
    while(next_prime<=max && is_composite[next_prime]) {
      next_prime+=2;
    }
  }

  // TODO: is there a beter way instead of iterating the list?  
  for(var i=2;i<=max;i++) {
    if(!is_composite[i]){
      primes.add(i);
    }
  }
  return primes;
}
```

Comment: Can you give a complete working example which shows your problem and describe what your want? I don't really understand from you description what your problem is and what you actually want.

Answer (score 0):

For the given algorithm you could properly reorder some stuff to make it easier to get the result by changing your `is_composite` list of boolean into a `is_not_composite` list of integers which are closer to what your want to return as the result:

```
List<int> findPrimes(int max) {
  final is_not_composite = List.generate(max + 1, (i) => i);

  for (var i = 4; i <= max; i += 2) {
    is_not_composite.remove(i);
  }

  var next_prime = 3;
  final stop = sqrt(max);

  while (next_prime <= stop) {
    for (var i = next_prime * 2; i <= max; i += next_prime) {
      is_not_composite.remove(i);
    }
    next_prime += 2;
    while (next_prime <= max && !is_not_composite.contains(next_prime)) {
      next_prime += 2;
    }
  }

  return is_not_composite.sublist(2);
}
```